# Phonegap n00b samples not working?

Tags: ios, cordova

Just started playing with the phonegap stuff, using latest XCode and latest phonegap (Cordova).

I followed the 'Getting started' stuff, everything seemed to work okay.  I copied the test code from the Camaera API samples, but none of the buttons work.  They show up in the simulator just fine, but when I click nothing at all happens.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I think that camera stuff doesn't work on simulator. Try on a real device. Also try with other API, like audio capture.

Comment: Does that also count for loading photos from the simulator camera roll?  I guess maybe there arent any there?  I would have thought I would get some error or something?

Comment: I don't know how the sample code is made, I just can speak about my own work. On simulator, calling camera API executes error callback because there is "no camera available". For camera roll it is just shown, but there are no pictures to choose.

Comment: I dont see anything.  No camera roll with no pictures to choose, nothing at all when I click... hmm